# How do I label vertices of polygons?

Tags: tikz-pgf, polygon

I am new to Tzik and only have basic knowledge, but I want to label the vertices of my polygon with non numeric symbols?

[image: It should look like (this has been made with Geogebra)]

but I only got

```
    \begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=45]
  \foreach \a in {0,90,180,270} { %\a is the angle variable
    \draw[line width=.7pt,black,fill=black] (\a:1.5cm) coordinate (a\a) circle (2pt); }
  \draw [line width=.7pt,black,fill=orange] (a0) -- (a90) -- (a180) -- (a270) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{3cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=22.5]
  \foreach \a in {0,45,90,135,180,225,270,315} { %\a is the angle variable
    \draw[line width=.7pt,black,fill=black] (\a:1.5cm) coordinate (a\a) circle (2pt); }
  \draw [line width=.7pt,black,fill=orange] (a0) -- (a45) -- (a90) -- (a135) -- (a180) -- (a225) -- (a270) -- (a315) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Please always post a complete, compilable example.

Answer (score 2):

`\foreach` can be used to loop over pairs (or more generally tuples) of values:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=22.5]
  \foreach \a/\l in {0/a,45/b,90/c,135,180,225,270,315} { %\a is the angle variable
    \draw[line width=.7pt,black,fill=black] (\a:1.5cm) coordinate (a\a) circle (2pt); 
    \node[anchor=202.5+\a] at ($(a\a)+(\a+22.5:3pt)$) {\l};
    }
  \draw [line width=.7pt,black,fill=orange] (a0) -- (a45) -- (a90) -- (a135) -- (a180) -- (a225) -- (a270) -- (a315) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

For each dot a label node is added with the actual label. Placement is fine tuned using anchors and needs `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` in the preamble.

Comment: @cfr yep sorry for that. Updated.

Comment: Great! and a bit