# How to place labels at calculated vertices of a polygonal path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have drawn a series of three perpendicular lines this way:

```
 \documentclass{amsart}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate [label= left:$B$] (B) at (-2.2,0);  
    \coordinate [label= right:$E$] (E) at (0.8,0); 
    \coordinate  (F) at (2.2,0);
    \draw (B) let
    \p1 = ($ (F) - (E) $), \p2 = ($ (E) - (B) $) 
    in  (E) -- +(0,{-veclen(\x1,\y1)}) [label= left:$C$]  -- 
    +({-veclen(\x2,\y2)},{-veclen(\x1,\y1)}) -- (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a direct way to put labels on the second and third vertices, which are calculated using \p1 and \p2?

You can see these vertices are not on a regular polygon as in question [How do I label vertices of polygons?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/322241/how-do-i-label-vertices-of-polygons)

And I also run into this problem with longer paths, where the steps are not perpendicular so a solution that relies on rectangles will not help me very much.

Edit: Okay, for this specific problem another solution would be to do a second let operation specifying the same \p1 and  \p2, and use it to place nodes instead of a path.   But that would not answer the question I am asking here.  Here i ask is there a direct way to put labels on vertices of a path when the vertices are specified by relative coordinates.

Comment: Rather than posting code fragments it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: @Andrew and cfr, MWE is now full.

Comment: Are you missing `coordinate` before label on purpose ?

Comment: @percusse No, that is an artifact left over from the way I got to this code.  Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use a node. It makes no difference that the coordinates are calculated: you'd need a node either way.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate [label= left:$B$] (B) at (-2.2,0);
  \coordinate [label= right:$E$] (E) at (0.8,0);
  \coordinate  (F) at (2.2,0);
  \draw (B) let \p1 = ($ (F) - (E) $), \p2 = ($ (E) - (B) $) in  (E) -- +(0,{-veclen(\x1,\y1)}) node [right] {$C$}  -- +({-veclen(\x2,\y2)},{-veclen(\x1,\y1)}) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: label in node]

## EDIT

Or, you can, of course, use coordinates.

```
  \coordinate [label= right:$E$] (E) at (0.8,0);
  \coordinate  (F) at (2.2,0);
  \draw (-2.2,0) coordinate [label=left:$B$] (B) let \p1 = ($ (F) - (E) $), \p2 = ($ (E) - (B) $) in (E) -- +(0,{-veclen(\x1,\y1)}) coordinate [label=right:$C$] (C)  -- +({-veclen(\x2,\y2)},{-veclen(\x1,\y1)}) coordinate [label=left:$G$] (G) -- (B);
```

Or you can exploit the fact that `midway` on a `|-` or `-|` path picks out the corner.

```
  \coordinate [label={[blue]right:$K$}] (K) at (.8,-2);
  \draw [blue] (-2.2,-2) coordinate [label=left:$H$] (H) let \p1 = ($ (2.2,-2) - (K) $), \p2 = ($ (K) - (H) $) in (K) |- +({-veclen(\x2,\y2)},{-veclen(\x1,\y1)}) coordinate [label=left:$G$] (G) coordinate [midway, label=right:$I$] (I) -- (H);
```

Or you can combine it all into one command.

```
  \draw [red] (-2.2,2) coordinate [label=left:$M$] (M) (.8,2) coordinate [label={[red]right:$L$}] (L) let \p1 = ($ (2.2,2) - (L) $), \p2 = ($ (L) - (M) $) in (L) |- +({-veclen(\x2,\y2)},{-veclen(\x1,\y1)}) coordinate [label=left:$O$] (O) coordinate [midway, label=right:$P$] (P) -- (M);
```

[image: three variations]

There are, obviously, easier ways of constructing these particular paths!

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate [label= right:$E$] (E) at (0.8,0);
  \coordinate  (F) at (2.2,0);
  \draw (-2.2,0) coordinate [label=left:$B$] (B) let \p1 = ($ (F) - (E) $), \p2 = ($ (E) - (B) $) in (E) -- +(0,{-veclen(\x1,\y1)}) coordinate [label=right:$C$] (C)  -- +({-veclen(\x2,\y2)},{-veclen(\x1,\y1)}) coordinate [label=left:$G$] (G) -- (B);
  \coordinate [label={[blue]right:$K$}] (K) at (.8,-2);
  \draw [blue] (-2.2,-2) coordinate [label=left:$H$] (H) let \p1 = ($ (2.2,-2) - (K) $), \p2 = ($ (K) - (H) $) in (K) |- +({-veclen(\x2,\y2)},{-veclen(\x1,\y1)}) coordinate [label=left:$G$] (G) coordinate [midway, label=right:$I$] (I) -- (H);
  \draw [red] (-2.2,2) coordinate [label=left:$M$] (M) (.8,2) coordinate [label={[red]right:$L$}] (L) let \p1 = ($ (2.2,2) - (L) $), \p2 = ($ (L) - (M) $) in (L) |- +({-veclen(\x2,\y2)},{-veclen(\x1,\y1)}) coordinate [label=left:$O$] (O) coordinate [midway, label=right:$P$] (P) -- (M);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ColinMcLarty Please see also edit.